# JavaScript did not receive value in this.form

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using a three part code below:

First part of the code: Basically a javascript function changeSearchEngine will be triggered when user select Google.

```
<p id="searchbox">This paragraph will change once javascript is triggered</p>
<form align=right>
<select name="searchengine" onchange="changeSearchEngine(this.form)">
<option value="google">Google</option>
</select>
</form>
```

This is my changeSearchEngine function in javascript.

```
function changeSearchEngine(form)
{
    var searchEngine=form.searchengine.value;
    if (searchEngine=="google")
    {
    var url_google='<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" onsubmit="submitGoogle(this.form)" target="_blank"><input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" /><input type="submit" value="Google Search"/></form>';
    document.getElementById("searchbox").innerHTML=url_google;
    }
}
```

At this point of time, all is working well. When I select Google, the searchbox for google appears. I can search and everything.

Notice there is a onsubmit="submitGoogle(this.form)" right? I need to save what the user search terms into SQL table. So I have this javascript function below to capture what user have type:

```
function submitGoogle(form)
{
    alert("Inside submitGoogle function");
        var searchterm=form.q.value;
    alert(searchterm); //to test. this part didnt capture the value.
}
```

I managed to invoke the submitGoogle function BUT however I can't retrieve the value of q despite using searchterm=form.q.value. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I *think* you have to use `onsubmit="submitGoogle(this)"` instead of `onsubmit="submitGoogle(this.form)"`. Also, it's considered good practice to separate markup from behavior, which, in this case, means binding event listeners with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) (falling back to `attachEvent` for older IE browsers), instead of adding JavaScript code in HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onsubmit` handler, you are passing `this.form`.  But, `this` already refers to the form since it is the form itself that triggers the `submit` event.  Form fields have a `form` property, but the form itself does *not* have a `form` property.  So, just change your handler to pass `this` instead of `this.form`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fmqNj/

```
onsubmit="submitGoogle(this)"
```

Comment: Ooh nice! Thanks for introducing me to jsfiddle.net. Didn't know of such tool to test.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found one possible solution. Let me answer my own question.

In changeSearchEngine(form) function, i change to this:

```
var url_google='<form method="get" name="googleform" action="http://www.google.com/search" onsubmit="submitGoogle(this.form)" target="_blank"><input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="hello" /><input type="submit" value="Google Search"/></form>';
```

In submitGoogle(form) function, i change to this:
    var searchterm=document.googleform.q.value;

But I still like others to comment on my solution whether it is not elegant or not within the practice. :D